# environment().put() and System.getenv() Linux

Tags: java, linux, jar, environment-variables, processbuilder

Okay, So I have a jar file called "MyOtherJar.jar", In it it does

```
String myenv = System.getenv("myenv");
```

And I execute that jar form another jar with this code,

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "MyOtherJar.jar");
 pb.environment().put("myenv", "foobar-barfoo");
 Process p = pb.start();
 BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
 while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
 }
 r.close();
```

It is working in windows, But for some reason it on linux it returns a null pointer exception when i try to access System.getenv("myenv");..  :/ Is there a way to set and get environment variables in linux..?

Comment: What does "won't work" mean for you?

Comment: It means it's not reading the environment variable. Null pointer exception.